# App crashes after adding Collapsing Toolbar

Tags: android

I am trying to achieve a Collapsing Toolbar just like many apps have, I tried adding it but it crashed my app

here is logcat

```
    11-11 12:51:18.622 18867-18867/com.koshur.socialnetwork E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-11 12:51:18.622 18867-18867/com.koshur.socialnetwork E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.koshur.socialnetwork, PID: 18867
11-11 12:51:18.622 18867-18867/com.koshur.socialnetwork E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.koshur.socialnetwork/com.koshur.socialnetwork.activities.ProfilePreview}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.getTitle()' on a null object reference
11-11 12:51:18.622 18867-18867/com.koshur.socialnetwork E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2357)
11-11 12:51:18.622 18867-18867/com.koshur.socialnetwork E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2419)
11-11 12:51:18.622 18867-18867/com.koshur.socialnetwork E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154)
11-11 12:51:18.622 18867-18867/com.koshur.socialnetwork E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
11-11 12:51:18.622 18867-18867/com.koshur.socialnetwork E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-11 12:51:18.622 18867-18867/com.koshur.socialnetwork E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
11-11 12:51:18.622 18867-18867/com.koshur.socialnetwork E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
11-11 12:51:18.622 18867-18867/com.koshur.socialnetwork E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-11 12:51:18.622 18867-18867/com.koshur.socialnetwork E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-11 12:51:18.622 18867-18867/com.koshur.socialnetwork E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
11-11 12:51:18.622 18867-18867/com.koshur.socialnetwork E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
11-11 12:51:18.622 18867-18867/com.koshur.socialnetwork E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.getTitle()' on a null object reference
11-11 12:51:18.622 18867-18867/com.koshur.socialnetwork E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.<init>(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:100)
11-11 12:51:18.622 18867-18867/com.koshur.socialnetwork E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.<init>(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:93)
11-11 12:51:18.622 18867-18867/com.koshur.socialnetwork E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.app.ToolbarActionBar.<init>(ToolbarActionBar.java:78)
11-11 12:51:18.622 18867-18867/com.koshur.socialnetwork E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:206)
11-11 12:51:18.622 18867-18867/com.koshur.socialnetwork E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:99)
11-11 12:51:18.622 18867-18867/com.koshur.socialnetwork E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.koshur.socialnetwork.activities.ProfilePreview.onCreate(ProfilePreview.java:81)
11-11 12:51:18.622 18867-18867/com.koshur.socialnetwork E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
11-11 12:51:18.622 18867-18867/com.koshur.socialnetwork E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
11-11 12:51:18.622 18867-18867/com.koshur.socialnetwork E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2310)
11-11 12:51:18.622 18867-18867/com.koshur.socialnetwork E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2419) 
11-11 12:51:18.622 18867-18867/com.koshur.socialnetwork E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154) 
11-11 12:51:18.622 18867-18867/com.koshur.socialnetwork E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321) 
11-11 12:51:18.622 18867-18867/com.koshur.socialnetwork E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
11-11 12:51:18.622 18867-18867/com.koshur.socialnetwork E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
11-11 12:51:18.622 18867-18867/com.koshur.socialnetwork E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293) 
11-11 12:51:18.622 18867-18867/com.koshur.socialnetwork E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
11-11 12:51:18.622 18867-18867/com.koshur.socialnetwork E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
11-11 12:51:18.622 18867-18867/com.koshur.socialnetwork E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904) 
11-11 12:51:18.622 18867-18867/com.koshur.socialnetwork E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
```

here is my .xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<org.buraktamturk.loadingview.LoadingView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/loginLoadingView"
    app:lv_color="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/userProfileCover"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        android:src="@drawable/header"/>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/head"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="#3f000000"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/userProfilePicture"
                            android:layout_width="80dp"
                            android:layout_height="80dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/userProfileName"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:text="Naveed"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/userProfileAddress"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:text="Naveed"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/userProfileJob"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:text="Naveed"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

                    </LinearLayout>
                </FrameLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
                    android:background="@color/primaryColor"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:text="Total Followers"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                            android:textStyle="bold"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/userTotalFollowers"

                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:text="1,573"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:text="Total Posts"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                            android:textStyle="bold"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/userTotalPosts"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:text="1,573"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/actionProfileArea"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="58dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"

                    android:visibility="visible">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/userPostsBtn"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:text="POSTS"
                        android:textColor="@color/primaryColor"
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/contactProfileBtn"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:text="CONTACT"
                        android:textColor="@color/primaryColor"
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/followProfileBtn"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:text="FOLLOW"
                        android:textColor="@color/primaryColor"
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
                android:id="@+id/swipeHome"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@id/app_bar">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView

                    android:id="@+id/postsList"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/postBg">

                </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
            </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</org.buraktamturk.loadingview.LoadingView>
```

this is my java Activity

```
  public class ProfilePreview extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {
    public TextView userProfileName,
            userTotalFollowers,
            userTotalPosts,
            userProfileAddress,
            userProfileJob,
            followProfileBtn,
            contactProfileBtn,
            userPostsBtn;
    public userItem user;
    public RecyclerView postsList;
    public LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
    int currentPage = 1;
    private HomeListAdapter mHomeListAdapter;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
    public ImageView userProfilePicture, userProfileCover;
    public LinearLayout actionProfileArea;
    public int userID = 0;
    private CacheManager mCacheManager;
    private ThinDownloadManager downloadManager;

    private Gson mGson;
    LoadingView loginLoadingView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (M.getToken(this) == null) {
            Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);

            startActivity(mIntent);
            finish();

        } else {
            setContentView(R.layout.layout_prof);
            initializeView();
            loginLoadingView = (LoadingView)findViewById(R.id.loginLoadingView);
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar =
                    (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
            if (getIntent().hasExtra("userID")) {
                userID = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("userID");
            }
            mCacheManager = CacheManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
            layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
            layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
            postsList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

            mHomeListAdapter = new HomeListAdapter(this, new ArrayList<PostsItem>());
            postsList.setAdapter(mHomeListAdapter);
            mGson = new Gson();
            getUser();
            getPosts();
        }

    }
```

Very very sorry if this post got too big.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your layout does not contain a toolbar, so

`Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);`

returns `null`

So the crash already occurs when you set the `SupportActionBar` because it tries to set the title on that `Toolbar`

Comment: what is the fix then?

Comment: Simply add a `Toolbar` to your `CollapsingToolbarLayout` as it is a wrapper around the `Toolbar`. Try this example: http://blog.grafixartist.com/toolbar-animation-with-android-design-support-library/